# setTimeout not delaying self.close() in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The following code is intended to close a Google Chrome extension pop-up 3 seconds after a user submits a form.

```
function closeIt() {
    self.close();
}

$('#logForm').html('<h2>Bookmark Added</h2>');
setTimeout(closeIt,3000);
```

If I call self.close() by itself in the flow of code it works properly to close the popup. However, in the example it doesn't appear to execute at all and exhibits no delay before the popup window refreshes itself.

I had tried experimenting with an alert a bit only to discover that alerts apparently interfere with setTimeout counting... I have also tried using "closeIt" with quotes to no avail.

UPDATE:
Thank you for the help! The popup is closing with the following code but there is no delay at all. The code is included in a function that runs on a submit of the form. Just to rule out a problem with the close function being the issue I also tried using $('#logForm').css('border', '3px double red'); in place of self.close() to see if there would be a delay and execution but there was not.

```
function closeIt() {
    self.close();
}

$('#logForm').html('<h2>Bookmark Added</h2>');
setTimeout(function() {closeIt();} ,3000);
```

Comment: Does `self` point to the right thing?

Comment: @alex - It appears too... it is closing the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
window.onload = function()
        {
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.close()
            },3000);
        }
```

Comment: OP is correct about passing function reference to setTimeout, otherwise your `closeIt()` will be executed right away.

Comment: then wrap it with another function:

setTimeout(function(){ closeIt(); }, 3000);

Comment: The code is currently running inside of a function like: $("#logForm").submit(function(){ //the code });